# Benefits of Windows 10 "Encrypt contents to secure data" file option with BitLocker

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, filesystems, encryption

I'm using Windows 10 and BitLocker for full-disk encryption. Recently I found that there is "Encrypt contents to secure data" attribute for files and folders.

[image: Windows 10 file Advanced Attributes]

If I'm already using BitLocker, are there benefits/reasons to use this feature?

Comment: "If I'm already using BitLocker, are there benefits/reasons to use this feature?" - One benefit is that only user(s) with the certificate used to encrypt the file can open the file.  Anyone with the ability to authenticate BitLocker can mount and unmount the volume and access any file contained on the drive.  There are already existing comparisons to EFS (Encrypted File System) and FDE (Full Disk Encryption).

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: @music2myear After reading an answer and comments, I learned that this feature is per-user encryption. So I tried turning on and off the feature on files and folders and created a new administrator account to check how it works. Reading the documentation on the internet

Answer (score 1):

Double encryption does not add much to your security; if your bitlocker is configured correctly, that should be fine.

Note that this built-in NTFS windows feature has some severe drawbacks - you will *not* be able to unencrypt such files on other machines or from another user ID, as it uses unique identification of the user ID. If you ever delete the user ID, all content is permanently lost - even if you create a new user ID with the same name.

Comment: It’s trivial to export and import  the certificate on another Windows machine. There are also benefits to using EFS in addition to FDE. The primary reason would be a multiple user situation, where FDE protects the entire disk, and EFS provides protection to each individual user